# Websocket error - One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a Node.js server running inside a Docker container. I'm trying to connect to the server using WebSockets from a web browser, but as soon as the connection is established, I get an error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain/api/websockets' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 0.
```

I accessed the Docker container and tried to connect using

```
wscat --header "Cookie:connect.sid=session-key" -c ws://127.0.0.1:5200/api/websockets
```

But got the error:

```
error: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear
```

I should note that during the initial connection, I receive valid data packets from the server, but shortly after, the connection drops with the aforementioned error.

Here's the code of the server:

```js
import WebSocket, { WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import { Server } from "http";
import { sessionParser } from "../passport";
import { User } from "../../share-types";
import { events, EventsList } from "./events";

export default async (server: Server) => {
    const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
        noServer: true,
        path: '/api/websockets',
    });
    server.on('upgrade', (request: Express.Request, socket, head) => {
        sessionParser(request, {}, () => {
            const user: User = request.session?.passport?.user;
            if (!user?.ID) return socket.destroy();
            wsServer.handleUpgrade(request as any, socket, head, (ws) => {
                wsServer.emit('connection', ws, request, user);
            });
        })
    });


    wsServer.on('connection', function (socket: WebSocket, request: Express.Request, user: User) {

        socket.on('error', console.error);
        socket.on('message', function (message) {
            try {
                message = JSON.parse(message.toString());
                events.emit(EventsList.NEW_WEB_SOCKET_MESSAGE, { user, message });
            } catch { }

        });
    });

    return wsServer;
};
```

WS package version:
"ws": "^8.16.0"

What could be the issue?

Comment: are you using an antivirus software?

Comment: @ITgoldman No, I also checked after disabling antivirus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is similar to [`websockets/ws` issue 2109](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/2109), which includes:

> I ran my original code in a remote server, hit it using Chrome, and it all worked properly. So it appears that the problem only happens when I am using localhost. Don't know why my localhost is bad yet.

And:

> I did eventually find a solution - use a port other than 8080.
>
> I still don't know why that port did not work, while others did. My theory is that Mac Docker was doing something weird with it that caused it to exhibit the behavior I found above, but once I found I could simply switch ports, I stopped investigating.

Also:

> Just as a reference for others you are banging their heads on this issue. We had a similar issue and it turned out to be the [Parental Control was enabled on the laptop which hijacked port 8080](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250500940). Conclusion: don't use 8080 on mac osx...

---

In your case, 8080 might not be involved, but try and switch port to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Amazing! I changed the port and it works. Thanks!